# How to set up multiple languages in Typo3 correctly?

Tags: typo3

this may be a noob question - but I hope to get an answer from an experienced person,
because we have to switch our settings and would like to do it correctly the first time.

At the moment the default language is set to German. English is defined as another language.
When somebody from France looks at the website, it is shown in German first, he then has to switch to english manually. For an english visitor everything is fine.

So what should we do:

1) Set the default language to english and have german as second language? What about guys from Switzerland, Luxemburg, Liechtenstein and Austria then. Do these have to be defined seperately as they are also seperately selectable as windows languages?

2) Is there an option to simply say: Every visitor that is not german speaking should get the english website in default? And even in this case, will this then recognize the different german options explained in 1?

Sorry if these questions are stupid. ;-)

Thank you,

Fabian

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53445690/6812729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aim is to change how visitors **see** the website, but your are asking how to change the **editing** of the website accordingly. Luckily it is a CMS and you can separate those concerns.

What you seem to look after is a component that analyses the IP/language/browser properties of the visitor at first page load and that there are rules what to show (e.g. show English version except your mentioned countries). There are extensions for that specific purpose like https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/locate or others: https://extensions.typo3.org/?L=0&id=1&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=language

That way you don't need to change the default at all.

Comment: Thank you that helps!